# C++ Inconsistent result by set_intersection method on unordered_set and set

Tags: c++, vector, set, intersection, unordered-set

I was working on a problem on Leetcode when I encountered this inconsistency with `unordered_set` and `set`.
Let two vectors be `nums1 = [4,9,5]` and `nums2 = [9,4,9,8,4]`. We have to find their intersection so I did the following two things:

1.

```
unordered_set<int> s1 (nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
unordered_set<int> s2 (nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
vector <int> s;
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), back_inserter(s));
```

2. Replaced `unordered_set` with `set`

```
set<int> s1 (nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
set<int> s2 (nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
vector <int> s;
set_intersection(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), back_inserter(s));
```

Result from approach 1. is `[9]` while from approach 2. is `[9,4]` (which is correct). Am I missing some key concepts of C++ STL?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection "Constructs a sorted range beginning at d_first consisting of elements that are found in both **sorted ranges** [first1, last1) and [first2, last2)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first snipped only first intersecting range is returned, because original set is unsorted

> Constructs a sorted range beginning at d_first consisting of elements
> that are found in both *sorted* ranges [first1, last1) and [first2,
> last2). If some element is found m times in [first1, last1) and n
> times in [first2, last2), the *first* std::min(m, n) elements will be
> copied from the first range to the destination range.

First sorted range is {4,9} and second sorted range is {9}.
Intersection of those two is indeed {9}.

For `set` {4,9} and {9,4} are equal and `set`s are sorted ranges. So both results are correct for given ranges.